# Variable declared in sql statement But cannot get the data to show

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am having an issue where the data is not showing up. When I put an OR on it it does show up but The or causes say user2 to have the same data as user1 .

```
<?php
      include 'users.php';
      require_once("db_connect.php");

     //prepared statement with PDO to query the database
     $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User='.$user1.' AND status='Received' ORDER BY id DESC);
     $stmt->execute();  
    ?>
```

users.php

```
<?php 

$user1 = xxxx;
$user2 = zzzz;

?>
```

Comment: `("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User='".$user1."' AND status='Received' ORDER BY id DESC")` - missing quotes and since we're probably dealing with strings, as suggested `xxx` unlike `123`. So please be specific if it's a string or an integer.

Comment: Fred Thank you I just realized I was missing double quotes

Comment: You need to use parameters in these queries unless you want a visit from my buddy bobby tables. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User='.$user1.' AND status='Received' ORDER BY id DESC);
```

IF `$user1 = 1`, then your SQL is going to be:

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User='.1.'.
```

You have double-quotes on the outer-string, so you are not escaping the string and concatenating, those will be literal dots, and you're never closing your outer-string at the end.  Also, I'm not sure of the point of using prepare if you are going to inject your variable directly into the string...?

Should look more like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User=:user AND status='Received' ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute(array(':user' => $user1));
```

If you want to do it your way, you can fix what looks like typos with:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User='".$user1."' AND status='Received' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

OR

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User='{$user1}' AND status='Received' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

However, both of these methods are NOT SAFE. They are at risk for SQL-Injection attacks.  You should use the prepared statement as I showed with the :user variable that PDO first sanitizes before injecting into your string.

To get your count:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows_cnt FROM requests WHERE status='Received' AND User=:user");  
$stmt->execute(array(':user'=>$user1));
if( false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) ) { 
    echo $row['rows_cnt'];  
}
```

Comment: the variable is $user1 I have it on another page which I include in users.php

Comment: is it ok to set the variable on it's on page?

Comment: It wasn't about where the variable was set, it was about the fact that you weren't concatenating like you were thinking you were.  Take a look at the example I added to the end.

Comment: also $user1 is dynamic so it can change at anytime.

Comment: I wanted to see if I can use the variable in the sql statement since user will change

Comment: @Veronica, yes, you can use it in the SQL statement.  The problem is the typos, not the variable.  However, the "safe" way to do it is as my example shows at the end.

Comment: oh sorry got it missing double quotes

Comment: I am going to delete this question. I was not paying attention sorry

Comment: @Veronica I'd just go with accepting the answer. But, the choice is *yours* ;) cheers

Comment: @Veronica, I don't think you can delete the question once it's been answered. However, I would encourage you to also read through the last stuff I added. There is very little point to using the prepare statement if you are going to inject variables directly into the string.  This opens you up for potential SQL-injection attacks. I would suggest it's worthwhile to see the "best-practices" way to do it using the :user var, etc., so that you can avoid possible SQL-injections.

Comment: Got it now I understand and will be using it the correct way

Comment: I tried the first statement you wrote on my count and it didn't work how would I be able to do it with count too?

Comment: @Veronica, I need to see the SQL that you are trying to get a count with...it depends on what you are doing. Sometimes you have to use a GROUP BY, etc.  Append it to your question if you can.

Comment: I append it to your answer by accident

Comment: @Veronica, yep, found that.  I didn't see any particular errors, but I did attempt to write it.  Are you trying to get the count of requests for each user, or a single count for a single user. As written, your count should only do the latter.  You need to use a GROUP BY if you want a count of each user.

Answer (score 0):

probably is a typo but seem that you don't close a `"`at the end of the line

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User='.$user1.' AND status='Received' ORDER BY id DESC);
```

So try this:

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE User='.$user1.' AND status='Received' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: ...and missing quotes for `User='.$user1.'` => `User='".$user1."'` since we're dealing with strings.